# VS code-runner:Main method not found in class,please define the main method or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

hope you doing great. So,I've been newly coding java on vscode using code-runner extension and i've encountred an issue:

> Main method not found in class MultiplyFun, please define the main method or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application.

here's my code
Notice: i wanted to make a main class to execute all

```
class MultiplyFun {

      // Method with 2 parameter
      static int Multiply(int a, int b) {
            return a * b;
      }

      // Method with the same name but 2 double parameter
      static double Multiply(double a, double b) {
            return a * b;
      }
}

class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(MultiplyFun.Multiply(2, 4));
            System.out.println(MultiplyFun.Multiply(5.5, 6.3));
      }
}
```

Comment: Use Java extension to run again. see if the error goes away.

Comment: Install this extension if you want to have full support for java: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack